# access the google compute server with a subdomain rather than external IP address

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I created a VM instance and deployed my application. I can access the application through the given external IP address, but I want to access it with some domain, just like openshift provides a domain AAA.rhcloud.com, which we can use the access the projects from the VM.

Is it possible to do it easily without normal DNS and CNAME route?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Most IP addresses have a DNS address than you can find out with reverse DNS:

```
$ dig +short -x 104.197.1.2
2.1.197.104.bc.googleusercontent.com.
```

As you can see on GCE you can reverse the IP address and append `bc.googleusercontent.com`. Of course this is no easier to remember than the IP address itself.

Between GCE instances in the same project, you can also use `INSTANCE_NAME.c.PROJECT_ID.internal`, but this won't work from outside GCE.